# Solve the system of equations for all real numbers $a$

Tags: systems-of-equations

I've the following matrix. I shall solve the system of equations for all real number of *a*.
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 2 & -3 & |4\\ 
3 & -1 & 5 & |2\\ 
4 & 1 & a^2-14 &|a+2 
\end{vmatrix}\Leftrightarrow
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 2 & -3 & |4\\ 
0 & -7 & 14 & |-10\\ 
0 & -7 & a^2-2 &|a-14 
\end{vmatrix}
\Leftrightarrow 
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 2 & -3 & |4\\ 
0 & -7 & 14 & |-10\\ 
0 & 0 & a^2-16 &|a-4 
\end{vmatrix}\\
z(a^2-14)=a+2\Rightarrow z=\frac{a-4}{a^2-16}\\
a\neq\pm4\\
z=\frac{a-4}{a^2-16}\Rightarrow z=\frac{1}{a+4}\\
$$
Then i put *z* in the second row to get $y=\frac{2}{a+4}+\frac{10}{7}$.

Then i put *y* and *z* in the first row to get $x=\frac{8}{7}- \frac{1}{a+4}$.

The answer is therefor:
$$(x,y,z)=(\frac{8}{7}- \frac{1}{a+4},\frac{2}{a+4}+\frac{10}{7},\frac{1}{a+4}) \ where \ a\neq\pm4$$

Have i understood this correct? What can i improve in the solution or in my thinking?

Comment: Looks good to me. One thing you should also do is consider the cases $a = \pm 4$. Let $a = 4$ in the original matrix and row reduce that. Also, when $a = -4$, there is no solution.

Comment: You could inspect the cases $a=4$ and $a=-4$.